# Spark : container is up but not starting job

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark job which starts well but all executor container shows :

```
INFO YarnAllocator: Received 1 containers from YARN, launching executors on 0 of them.
```

And the mapreduce job is like this :

```
>>> Invoking Shell command line now >>

Stdoutput spark.driver.cores is set but does not apply in client mode.
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
```

And it does not start working. I tried reduce the spark.executor.instances to 1 and it works, but when I change back to 4 it hangs like this.

I think it's a configuration problem, what should I do ?
My config :

```
spark.driver.cores=1
spark.driver.memory=2g
spark.yarn.am.cores=1
spark.yarn.am.memory=4096m
spark.executor.instances=4
spark.executor.cores=4
spark.executor.memory=2g
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check whether the spark cluster can submit a simple job normally, for example:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 1g \
--executor-cores 1 \
examples/jars/spark-examples*.jar \
10
```